# Bootstrap navbar collapse not working with bundled bootstrap files

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I want to include a navbar that I copied from the bootstrap example page in views of my asp.net application. The navbar is as follows,

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
   <a class="navbar-brand" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Bata</a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
         <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
         </li>
         @if (signInManager.IsSignedIn(User) && User.IsInRole("Admin"))
         {
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" asp-action="ListUsers" asp-controller="Admin">User Management</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" asp-action="ListPurchases" asp-controller="Purchase">Purchases</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" asp-action="ListCurrencies" asp-controller="Admin">Currency Management</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" asp-action="List" asp-controller="unitItem">Inventory Management</a>
         </li>
         }
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="Contact" action="Index">Contact</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
      @await Component.InvokeAsync("CheckoutSummary")
      @await Html.PartialAsync("LoginPartial")
      <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
         <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
         <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
   </div>
</nav>
```

The navbar displays properly but it will not collapse when the button is clicked. The button is getting the click event you can tell since the button turns orange.

I have bundled my bootstrap and js files like this and include the vendor files in the view.

```
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/vendor.min.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css.map",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css.map",
    ],
    "minify": { "enabled": true }
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/vendor.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js.map",
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
    ],
    "minify": { "enabled": false }
  }
]
```

Is there something I could be missing why the collapse button is not working?

Comment: Not sure how this is build, but shouldn't jQuery import be on top?!

Comment: I tried this, but it didnt work. I also have another jquery reference for jquery.validate on bottom of the page and still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you confirm if other scripts are working? Try to type `jQuery` in the console to see if it's there.

Comment: jquery is working

Comment: Try `$('#navbarCollapse').collapse('toggle')`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219189/discussion-between-ndcweb-and-paul-gudu).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to copy the functionality of the last example on the navbar page. If so, it looks like you are missing some of their classes. try including them.

Here is the code from their example. For testing you could try starting with their example and slowly incorporate what you want to be in the navbar. This will help you figure out what you are missing.

```
<div class="pos-f-t">
  <div class="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
    <div class="bg-dark p-4">
      <h4 class="text-white">Collapsed content</h4>
      <span class="text-muted">Toggleable via the navbar brand.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  </nav>
</div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#external-content

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but this doesn't seem to work either, I even tried just adding removing my navbar and adding the example but it still doesn't work

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. But I think that rules out problems in your html. That makes me think it must be a problem with the bundled files.